# Issues with slicing and retrieving maximum of slice. Array is empty?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, slice, empty-list

So I am trying to loop 16 times through the code below. The error message says

> ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has
>   no identity

I printed the vorticity_array_850mb before the loop with numbers instead of variables started and it worked:

> print 'the vorticity array slice is',
>   vorticity_array_850mb[0:46,0:32]

But when I took the max of the sliced value within the loop it did not work, because the vorticity_array_850mb is supposedly empty:

```
  print 'the vorticity array slice is', vorticity_array_850mb[0:46,0:32]
  for row_start in range(0,128, 32):  
     for column_start in range(0,184, 46):
        print vorticity_array_850mb[column_start: column_start+46,row_start:row_start+32]
        max_value = np.amax(vorticity_array_850mb[column_start:column_start+46, row_start:row_start+32])
        vor_max_list.append(max_value)
```

Can you please give a reason why the array is empty? And how can possibly fix it?

Comment: You probably want to show more code, as vorticity_array_850mb doesn't seem to be initialized anywhere in the code you are showing

Comment: First, that print outside the loop doesn't establish anything useful. Just because the slice from `[0:46, 0:32]` is non-empty doesn't mean the slice from `[138:184, 96:128]` is. What if the shape is, say, `(138, 96)`?

Comment: Meanwhile, can you turn this into a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that other people can test without needing to get a copy of your 850MB file and all your code and read through probably hundreds of lines of debugging output? (If you can't, your odds of getting an answer are not that good.)

Comment: Meanwhile, why is this tagged [empty-list] and [loops]?

Comment: Thank you abarnert I think that maybe part of the problem